# Identical shebang not working

Tags: python, tcsh, shebang

So I'm trying to create some scripts that I want to run without manually specifying the interpreter each time I run it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Above is the shebang on an existing script that runs like I want it to.

Below is the shebang of a script I wrote from scratch

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

To me they look identical, but running the second one gives me a

```
helloWorld.py: permission denied
```

Both have been created using kate, utf-8 and unix lines.
Both are identical to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is complaining about the permissions, not the shebang line.  What are the permissions of both files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shebang may be correct, but the script also needs execute permissions.

```
# Anyone can execute
chmod +x helloworld.py

# Only the file owner can execute
chmod u+x helloworld.py
```

Comment: thanks! That was it...used chmod for other permission stuff...somehow spaced on setting executable

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the permissions of the script. Try:

```
chmod u+x helloWorld.py
```

and run again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the permission of /usr/bin/python but rather of the actual script.

If you are running from the command line and not passing the script name as an argument to python then the script has to be executable.

If it is not then fix using chmod `chmod +x helloworld.py`